# Datagrid textblock not aligned on left border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

This is probably a very stupid problem, which is also probably why I can't find an answer to it.

I have a datagrid in which I add messages every once in a while during a lengthy operation, and for some reason the textblocks appear slightly a bit on the right of the left border of the datagrid, even though there is no margin on the textblock and no padding on the datagrid :

[image]

Here is my XAML :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrdMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="202" Width="690">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Message" Width="*">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsError}" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` on `DataGridCell`....

Comment: There is no such property on `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>`, tried to set it on the `<DataGrid>` but it didn't work

Comment: Add `DataGridCell Style` inside `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle >...</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>` with `HorizontalContentAlignment` Setter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it does not seems the TextBlock are "slightly on the right" (they touch the left border).
Do you want to get rid of the "row selector", the small gray button on the left? 
If so set HeadersVisibility="Column" in XAML.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you ! It's strange though, I have used Datagrids before in the same project and didn't have that issue... Anyway, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
     </Style>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how I'd do that with two Grid.ColumnDefinitions, where I want the first column to be left-aligned and the second column to be right-aligned?

Comment: Ended up using <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">